# Prevent Slider Revolution from pausing HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, revolution-slider

I'm using the Themepunch Revolution slider in a project, which shows a single video slide in HTML 5.

When I click on it, it pauses, which I don't want.

The `<video>` element in the page is generated by the slider plugin.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
$('body').on('click', 'video', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

This is the code in the slider library:

```
html5vid.find('video, .tp-poster, .tp-video-play-button').click(function() {
    if (html5vid.hasClass("videoisplaying"))
        video.pause();
    else
        video.play();
})
```

I also tried catching the pause event, but it never fires:

```
$('body').on('pause', 'video', ...);
```

Comment: well, isn't the code in the slider library telling you why it's pausing? it's checking whether it's running, if so it will pause... don't think you can override that outside the library unless you edited the script...

Comment: ...have you tried unbinding `click`?

Comment: @webeno yeah my only working solution so far is directly removing the lines from the library, which is ugly  :(

Answer (score 5):

For Revolution `Slider 6.x`, it's easier, just select the video layer `option > Content > (Scroll down) Advanced Media Settings > Set "No Interaction" off`

This will disable the click to pause/play also remove controls, you end up with a playing video with no interactions, also don't forget to set `Loop Media` on for complete experience

Revolution Slider No Interaction Setting to prevent controls and stop click for play/pause:
[image: Revolution Slider No Interaction Setting to prevent controls and stop click for play/pause]

Answer (score 1):

Hey it is 2019 but anyone who look for solution is that :

Put transparent shape layer onto video layer as full width and height.

Make sure put this layer one step above the video layer as showing below(this shape looks like it below the video layer but in rev slider animation settings the more bottom the more up on the front-end i hope i make it clear :)

[Layer positions on rev slider animation settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWvBJ.png)

Comment: Thank you also my friend i'm really appreciated if it is work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```javascript
html5vid.find('video, .tp-poster, .tp-video-play-button').unbind('click');
```

Replace `html5vid` with whatever element the script is looking to find in.

**EDITED**

...or better yet, try to unbind `click` on the `video` element as follows:

```javascript
$('video').unbind( "click" );
```

Comment: Doesn't work..the find() is executed after I call the revolution() script, at which point it hasn't made the video element yet.

Comment: have you tried unbinding click from the `video` element? `$('video').unbind( "click" );`